# Save programmatically created picturebox control and reload

Tags: c#, save, controls, load, picturebox

Actually I am in trouble. My project is to create a desktop with shortcuts. The desktop is ready, it is a picturebox as background. And now the shortcuts.

Through a dialog, I will create a shortcut on the picturebox (desktop). Example:
Here is my desktop:
https://pasteboard.co/IHSdXvX.png

Here is my dialog:
https://pasteboard.co/IHSefrz.png
First textbox is the path to the file. Second textbox is the name of the shortcut.

And here is the result:
https://pasteboard.co/IHSeM7Y.png 
In the upper left corner is a new green shortcut. It is a picturebox, which was created by this code:

```
 Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(textBox1.Text);

        var picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = textBox2.Text,
            Size = new Size(48, 46),
            Location = new Point(100, 100),
            Image = ico.ToBitmap(),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,

        };


        Form1Singleton.FormVerweis.pictureBox1.Controls.Add(picture);
```

So, my question is:

How can I save the new created picturebox (the green icon upper left corner) and load it back to the same position, and the same click-Event to start the .exe behind it (exe path in textbox 1 in the dialog before) when the application starts. Information about the picturebox to save: Location, Icon, .exe Path.

Thanks for your help and I am really happy about code-examples. 
Joshua

Comment: Have a read about [serialization](https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-serialization.html). Don't serialize the PictureBox tho but the values that you need to be able to programmatically restore it when loading the application.

Comment: And how should i load it back? I have to create a new picturebox at startup and load the values from the file into it?

Comment: That is correct! Best if you have a method that takes some parameters and creates the picturebox which you can use for your existing process (eg. `CreateIcon(string path, string name, int x, int y, int width, int height)` which you can call with `textbox1.text, textbox2.text, 48, 46, 100, 100`) and then also at startup when loading using the values that you deserialized.

Comment: I created your example. But the problem is, that I don't know, how to serialize it, and i read the article you send...
I have to serialize it after creating the icon and deserialize it, when loading the mainform. Two different forms...

Comment: I don't know, what i have to use as object. Do you unterstand?

Comment: I'll write up an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a class that stores all the information you need to create an icon:

```
[Serializable]
public class IconDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have some method that actually creates your icon based on these values:

```
void createIcon(IconDefinition iconDefinition)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox()
    {
        Name = iconDefinition.Name,
        Size = new Size(iconDefinition.Width, iconDefinition.Height),
        Location = new Point(iconDefinition.X, iconDefinition.Y),
        Image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(iconDefinition.Path).ToBitmap(),
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    };
    pictureBox.Click += myClickHandler;
    Form1Singleton.FormVerweis.pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
}
```

Next you have your methods to serialize and deserialize these. Since you probably want to store all your icons in the same file for persistence you would use a `List` for serialization.

```
static void saveIcons(List<IconDefinition> icons)
{
    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@".\icons.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Read))
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, icons);
}

static List<IconDefinition> loadIcons()
{
    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@".\icons.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        return (List<IconDefinition>)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
}
```

These will provide you functionality to write a `List<IconDefinition>` to a file, or restore it from a file.

Now you will have to have a place somewhere to put all your icons:

```
List<IconDefinition> allIcons = new List<IconDefinition>();
```

When manually creating the icon (as you do already):

```
IconDefinition iconDefinition = new IconDefinition()
{
    Path = textBox1.Text,
    Name = textBox2.Text,
    X = 100,
    Y = 100,
    Width = 48,
    Height = 46
};
allIcons.Add(iconDefinition);
createIcon(iconDefinition);
```

When you want to save all your icons:

```
saveIcons(allIcons);
```

And when your application starts to restore them:

```
// When application starts you can load the icons
allIcons = loadIcons();
// then restore them all
foreach (IconDefinition definition in allIcons)
    createIcon(definition);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot! 

One last question: Where and how can i put in a click-handler for the picturebox?

Comment: No idea? :/ I would like to do that, but I don't have a picture box object, which I can do following: pic.click += new Eventhandler ()

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't able to reply. I don't see a reason why the normal click handler `.MouseClick += handler` shouldn't work. You may want to open a new question for this issue.

Comment: Hey, the problem is, that don't know, where I have to place this code snippet into the code you wrote above. That's all...

Comment: Best do it inside the `createIcon` method so that every time the picturebox is created (manually or by loading from file) it also restores the event.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how there?

Comment: What do you mean? You have the picturebox there, add the event handler before or after adding it to the `pictureBox1.Controls`.

Comment: Form1Singleton.FormVerweis.pictureBox1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox(Click += new Eventhandler(click_icon) does not work....

Comment: you can't put event handlers in the constructor. `PictureBox myPictureBox = new PictureBox() {...}; myPictureBox.Click += ...; ...pictureBox1.Controls.Add(myPictureBox);`

Comment: Yes, I know that. And where do I put the Picturebox myPictureBox = new Picturebox? I am sorry, but I am a little bit confused now.

Comment: I've updated the `createIcon` method of the example in my answer to show the example how it would be written.

Comment: Thank you for your help and support!